# Beginner Python Code Problem with the Mean Calculator function

Tags: python

For some reason in the code, I was testing whether it would work with two numbers, but the `a` variable would be 2 once I typed it out, but the code said when I run it is that it is not 2. What is the problem? Also I used Pycharm if that's part of the problem.

```
def part1(Answer1, Answer2):
x=Answer1+Answer2
y=x/2
print(y)

print("What are your numbers? 2 max")
a=input("How many numbers would you like? :")
Answer1=input("What is your first number? :")
Answer2=input("What is your second number? :")

if a==2:
    part1(Answer1, Answer2)
else:
    print(a)
```

Comment: Please indent the code correctly.  Python is dependent on indentation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I read inputs as numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-numbers)

Comment: Note that the number 2 and the string "2" print the same but are different values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) returns a string:

```
a=input("How many numbers would you like? :")
print(type(a)) # str
```

You need to convert it to the int (the same for `Answer1` and `Answer2`):

```
a=int(input("How many numbers would you like? :"))
```